# hide div in Angular if is logged in user

Tags: angular

I try to hide a div when the user is logged in, using auth service in Angular and token from Django

**Component.html**

```
<a *ngIf="authService.isLogedin()" style="color:white"   href="/#/login" class="nav-link" (click)="logOut()">Cerrar sesión</a>
```

**auth service.ts**

```
islogedin: boolean = false;

private setSession(authResult) {
  const token = authResult.token;
  const payload = <JWTPayload> jwtDecode(token);
  const expiresAt = moment.unix(payload.exp);

  localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.token);
  localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
}

isLogedin() {

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).auth_token == null) {
      this.islogedin = false;
      return this.islogedin;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: *ngIf will not triger a function. He can listen for some variable but not trigger function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next, to prevent errors in JSON.parse.

```
isLogedin() {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   this.islogedin = token && JSON.parse(token) != null;
   return this.islogedin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the service directly into the html component

You have to make the service injection in the constructor and use that it in

In component.ts

```
islogedin: boolean;

constructor (private authService:AuthService)
{islogedin= authService.isLogedin();

}
```

Then in html component use like this

component.html

```
         <a *ngIf="islogedin" style="color:white"   href="/#/login" class="nav-link" (click)="logOut()">Cerrar sesión</a>
```

Comment: thnx for comments, i copy you code bro and send me this now... [link](https://prnt.sc/pj901o)

Comment: Why are you parsing the token it is starting with e please share your local storage value